# Closed form of arctanlog series

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

What tools would you recommend me for 
$$\operatorname{arctan}\left( \frac{1}{1}\right)\log\left(1+\frac{1}{1}\right)+\operatorname{arctan}\left( \frac{1}{2}\right)\log\left(1+\frac{1}{2}\right)+\operatorname{arctan}\left( \frac{1}{3}\right)\log\left(1+\frac{1}{3}\right)+\cdots$$? Adding some parameters and then differentiating lead me to some hard-to-approach
polygamma  expressions. What else to try?

Comment: An idea? I don't know this would help or not
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \arctan\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_{0}^{1/n}\frac{d}{dx}\bigg(\arctan\left(x\right)\ln\left(1+x\right)\bigg)dx\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_{0}^{1/n}\left(\frac{\ln(1+x)}{1+x^2}+\frac{\arctan(x)}{1+x}\right)dx
\end{align}

Comment: It's the imaginary part of $$\frac12\sum_{n=1}^\infty \log\left(\frac{n+i}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^2$$

Comment: Is there a reason to think it has a closed form? It is definitely less than $\zeta(2)$.